# Copying a distinct sqlite table grouped by single column results in IntegrityError: Column is not unique (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, cursor, unique

I have a relatively small sqlite3 database (~2.6GB) with 820k rows and 26 columns (single table). Within this database there is a table named old_table, at the moment I created this table I had no primary key, and therefore adding new rows was prone to having duplicates being added.

In terms of efficiency, I created the same database again, but this time with the column Ref set as primary key: `'Ref VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,'`. According to many resources, we should be able to select only the unique rows based on a single column with the query `SELECT * from old_table GROUP BY Ref`. I want to keep the unique values so I insert them into a new table with `INSERT INTO new_table`. Afterwards I would like to drop the old table with `DROP TABLE old_table`. Finally, the new_table should be renamed to old_table with `ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO new_table`.

Why does my sql state that column Ref is not unique?

```
#Transferring old database to new one, with ref as unique primary key

#And delting old_table

conn = connect_to_db("/mnt/wwn-0x5002538e00000000-part1/DATABASE/database.db")
c = conn.cursor()   
c.executescript(""" 
    INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * from old_table GROUP BY Ref;
    DROP TABLE old_table;
    RENAME TO new_table
    """)

conn.close()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IntegrityError: column Ref is not unique
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO new_table`?

Comment: Even when removing this statement completely, or the last two statements, it returns the same error

Comment: The following method is working: `CREATE TABLE new_table as SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old_table` , however this is very memory inefficient, and does not allow me to make primary key in new table.

Comment: It seems 3 of my Ref IDs are not unique, as I parsed the original column into a list and reviewed them. The statement as described in the question ` SELECT * from old_table GROUP BY Ref` does seem to return a list with unique items only. I even placed this returned table in a completely new table, and tried to pipe this into the new_table, but the same error returns, meaning: `IntegrityError: column Ref is not unique` is coming forth from the fact that I try to pipe a datatype (Ref) that is not unique into a column with datatype that is unique. Still did not solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, later I found that the new table had 1 column in different order, being exactly the column set as unique, and not being unique.